# How to pass data from child popup window to parent window in angular?

Tags: angular

I have created an angular component where users can log in to Instagram and get the auth token in a popup window. After the user log in successfully in the popup window I was able to get the auth code in the redirect URL of the popup window. Now I would like to close the popup window. But before closing the pop-up window I would like to send this auth code to the parent window. How can I do that?

Does anyone have any solution?

Here is the HTML:

```
<label nz-radio-button nzValue="default" (click)="goto()">
  Instagram
</label>
```

and Ts. file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParam => {
      this.code = queryParam.get('code');
      if (this.code) {
           // after logging in to the popup window I was able to get the auth code
       }
      }

     goto() {
        const url = `${environment.instagramApiUrl}${environment.redirectUrl}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code`
        // let test = window.opener(url);
        // console.log(test)
    
        /* Step 1 : Open popup */
        this.parentWindow = this.popup(url, 'test', 500, 800)
    
      }
    
      popup(url, title, width, height) {
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
        var options = '';
        options += ',width=' + width;
        options += ',height=' + height;
        options += ',top=' + top;
        options += ',left=' + left;
        return window.open(url, title, options);
    }
```

Now after logging in successfully, the redirect URL brings back the user on the same component, therefore I was able to detect the auth code via queryparams in the popup window. Now I would like to close the popup window and return the auth code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution. `Windows.opener.postMessage` method helped me to pass the data from the popup window to the parent windows. Here is my solution down below. Hope that might help others.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParam => {
      this.code = queryParam.get('code');
      if (this.code) {
        window.opener.postMessage({ code: this.code }, '*');
        window.close();
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
      if (e.data.code) {
      console.log(e.data.code) // you will get the auth code from popup
      }
    }        
  }
```